# How to dynamically create a div/card with Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

So I have a card-container that will hold information that I want to dynamically fill. I currently have it filled with static information. I've been trying to figure a way to use jquery to clone the initial div and then fill the card with information and add but im quite stomped and cant seem to figure a work around. Below is the container is the container im using. First thought was to try and save the div in a variable and then call it in my document section, but im able to edit as it not a function then for some reason.

```
    <div class="blog-container">

      <div class="blog-header">
        <div class="blog-author--no-cover">
          <h3>Russ Beye</h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="blog-body">
        <div class="blog-title">
          <h1><a href="#">This Post Has No Cover Image</a></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="blog-summary">
          <p>Here is an example of a post without a cover image. You don't always have to have a cover image. In
            fact, leaving them out from time to time and disrupt the predictive flow and make the overall design
            more interesting. Something to think about.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="blog-tags">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">design</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">web dev</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">css</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="blog-footer">
        <ul>
          <li class="published-date">12 days ago</li>
          <li class="comments"><a href="#"><svg class="icon-bubble">
                <use xlink:href="#icon-bubble"></use>
              </svg><span class="numero">8</span></a></li>
          <li class="shares"><a href="#"><svg class="icon-star">
                <use xlink:href="#icon-star"></use>
              </svg><span class="numero">3</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is the document area below, im just generating random tweets and i want to be able to create the above div and use jquery to edit certain spots and then append the document. Any suggestions or clues would be great.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $card = $(".blog-container").prop('outerHTML')
  var $body = $('body');
  var $test = $('col2-main')
  //$body.html('');
  var index = streams.home.length - 1;
  while (index >= 0) {
    var tweet = streams.home[index];
    var $tweet = $('<div></div>');
    $tweet.text('@' + tweet.user + ': ' + tweet.message);
    $(".blog-summary").find("p").text('@' + tweet.user + ': ' + tweet.message);
    $(".col2-main").append($card)
    index -= 1;
  }
});
```

Comment: might need to be `$card.find(".blog-summary p")`

Comment: Currently if works and it adds the new sections, but it adds the same text over and over again because its looking at the current dom replacing all current p's. Was hoping to have a way to have the div be away from it all so i can generate a "fresh" div and populate it with new info

Comment: Ya Uncaught TypeError: $card.find is not a function Is what i keep getting.

Comment: Ups should be `$($card).find(".blog-summary p")`

Comment: Ya that got rid of that error, now the paragraph just doesnt update. Getting close though!

Comment: I don't know if it works, but you could try `var $card = $(".blog-container").clone()`

Comment: Was able to get clone to work by just taking the first element of the array. Since everytime it got cloned it was larger and larger so I just took the first index and edited that one. Much thx friend!